# Is there any other command to auto reload webpage?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed live-server globally and ran the command *live-server --port=9000* to auto-reload but it shows some errors..!

```
events.js:
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
 errno: 'ENOENT',
 code: 'ENOENT',
 syscall: 'spawn cmd',
 path: 'cmd',
 spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' ]
}
```

Is there any other command before installing it?

Comment: Try to install Nodemon from npm...

Comment: Tried this but same errors...